# Highcharts: use of PointClass in Angular

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to apply a tooltip to plotLines as shown in this example: `http://jsfiddle.net/tw6rmc1r/2/`

I'm stuck at this line: `PointClass = series.pointClass`

I can't manage to create the PointClass object. I can't really find the equivalent definition in Angular.

Please can you help me creating that Object in Angular?

Thank you :)

Comment: Or do you know another way of adding a custom tooltip to a PlotLine, in Angular?

Comment: With what do you exactly struggle? Is the TS the issue? Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-hpaxn8

Comment: My main problem is that I don't understand how to use the "this" object for the chart. In my case, I implemented the chart exactly like in your example, but "this" always refers to the Angular component where I implemented the chart. So for example when I use "(this as any).axis.series[0]" it returns undefined, because "this.axis" doesn't exist. How do I make "this" refer to the chart? Or how can I refer to it?

Comment: The easiest way to use `chart` reference is by creating that reference in the chart callback as I did in the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-wttx6n